# Changing Flash permissions for specific website on Edge

Tags: permissions, website, flash, microsoft-edge

I want to allow Flash to always execute for a specific website on Edge. I clicked on the *three dots > Settings > Advanced > Manage Permissions and selected the website*, but the only permission I see is media autoplay.

How can I see (or enable) the Flash options (and other permissions) for a specific website on Edge? Here are some screenshots (The screens are in Brazillian Portuguese):

[Advanced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ni0W1.png), [Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTQ1g.jpg), [Website Permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTz2o.png).

Answer (score 0):

There are two things that need to be done to achieve this...

1.Enable flash in Edge - This can be done by clicking the dots to the right > select settings > select advanced settings in the LH pane > toggle slider to allow flash.

2.Go to the specific website > click the puzzle piece icon to the right of URL > select always allow.

Comment: Flash is Enabled. When I click the puzzle piece the only option there is **Allow once**.